# Al validar los datos, no redirige la vista a home despues del login

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-8

[image: Validados los datos del acceso]

[image: Lo que me muestra la consola]

Datos de acceso en la imagen 1

Lo que muestra la consola en la imagen 2

Mi codigo de redireccionamiento

```
if($user->nom_us == $request->usuario && $user->clave == $request->password){
                    $result['success']=true;
                    return view('dashboard.index');
```

Mi ruta de acceso

`Route::get('/dashboard',[DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('home');`

Al realizar todos estos pasos, aun asi. No muestra la vista ya dentro del sistema. Cabe destacar que el HTML esta hecho en Vue, anteriormente funcionaba pero solo con el superadministrador, es decir el usuario por defecto generado mediante laravel.

Comment: ¿La clave en la base de datos esta *hasheada*?

Comment: No, esta simple por el momento

Comment: Si pegas todo el método controlador, sería mejor... Pero, si no renderiza el view, es que no se cumple la condición. También añadir que laravel tiene un middleware de login, así no puedes omitirte el if y solo hacer el `return view('dashboard.index')`